# Inner loop to iterate only once over every outer loop element

Tags: javascript

Am a bit lost in how to make the following template literal loop to work, so the outcome would be:

`"... 17C in 1 days."`
`"... 21C in 2 days."`
 `"...23C in 3 days"`

My code is the following so far, but I'm sure you can see the problem:

```js
let testData1 = [17, 21, 23];


function printForecast(arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (let day = 1; day <= 3; day++) {
      console.log(`...${arr[i]}C in ${day} days`)
    }
  }
}
printForecast(testData1)
```

Comment: If you want a loop "to iterate only once", then you don't want a loop.

Comment: Thank you for all the answers! Simple and understandable for myself. :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
let testData1 = [17, 21, 23];

function printForecast (arr) {
   for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
         console.log(`...${arr[i]}C in ${i+1} days`)
      
   }
}

printForecast(testData1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the inner loop at all.

```
let testData1 = [17, 21, 23];

function printForecast (arr) {
   for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
       console.log(`...${arr[i]}C in ${i+1} days`);
   }
}
printForecast(testData1)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can just use a single `for loop` in this case, with a minor revision.

```js
function printForecast (arr) {
   for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    // i + 1 would give us “1, 2, and 3” for the 3 iterations
     console.log(`...${arr[i]}C in ${i + 1} days`)
   }
}
```